# Optimize VPS ( Apache,Mysql,Apc )

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, vps

I have VPS With this specification:

**CPU Power 3,000 MHz
Guaranteed RAM  1,024 MB
Guaranteed FlexRAM* 2,048 MB**

I have hosted Social Network Script ( Social Engine PHP Script )
This script use Inno_DB working on Zend Framework.

I have loading time more then 30 secounds.Also plesk for more then 30 secounds per listing.
I use Debian 5.0 with APC Engine installed.

**My question is**

1. Did i need to optimize apache?
2. Mysql Inno_DB tables
3. APC Configuration

Also,working slow PhpMyAdmin,Everything inside.Listing from FTP with FileZilla it's okey.
The page don't have visitors.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your whole instance might be struggling.  The specs certainly seem good enough on paper, but it's possible your resources are being unfairly contended by other instances running on the same host.  Of course, there might be a process within your instance that's stealing all your CPU cycles - if you run `top` do you see any rogue processes?

You can also run `free` to check that you've got RAM headroom.

Answer (score 0):

When you are experiencing slow performance, what you want to be looking for is the bottleneck.

I recommend running some form of Monitoring software, I personally like Munin (http://library.linode.com/server-monitoring/munin/debian-5-lenny). I would leave the server running with the monitoring software for about a week and then check the results, which should hopefully show where your poor performance is coming from.